# javascript reference to prototype function is undefined in constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Given the following object:

```
function MyObject() {
  window.myFunc1 = this.myFunc1;
  window.myFunc2 = this.__proto__.myFunc2;
}

MyObject.prototype.anotherFunc = function () {
  window.myFunc3 = this.myFunc3;
  window.myFunc4 = this.__proto__.myFunc4;
}

MyObject.prototype.myFunc1 = function () { console.log(1); }

MyObject.prototype.myFunc2 = function () { console.log(2); }

MyObject.prototype.myFunc3 = function () { console.log(3); }

MyObject.prototype.myFunc4 = function () { console.log(4); }

var o = new MyObject();
o.anotherFunc();
window.myFunc1();
window.myFunc2();
window.myFunc3();
window.myFunc4();
```

In [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63dbgcfe/) I'm getting what is expected, but when testing with an ios app under ionic framework the results (tested with safari debugger) are:

```
  window.myFunc1 -> undefined
  window.myFunc2 -> it works!
  window.myFunc3 -> it works!
  window.myFunc4 -> it works!
```

Isn't the prototype attached to the object before it is created?

**EDIT**

attached fiddle and working example, fine tuned the question

Comment: Uh, are you actually calling `MyObject` and `anotherFunc` anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm getting the following results […]

I cannot reproduce that. Try this:

```
function MyObject() {
  console.log(this.myFunc1);
  console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(this).myFunc2);
}
MyObject.prototype.anotherFunc = function () {
  console.log(this.myFunc3);
  console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(this).myFunc4);
}

MyObject.prototype.myFunc1 = function () { }
MyObject.prototype.myFunc2 = function () { }
MyObject.prototype.myFunc3 = function () { }
MyObject.prototype.myFunc4 = function () { }

var o = new MyObject();
o.anotherFunc()
```

> Isn't the prototype attached to the object before it is created?

Uh, no. The prototype cannot really be attached to a non-existing object :-) Best think of it as happening simultaneously, that an object is created with a prototype, it doesn't exist without one.

What you might have meant that the object (with its prototype) is created before the constructor is executed - yes.

Comment: Then I'm not understanding why `this.myFunc1` in object creator is undefined

Comment: It was not. Your example is unreproducable. Maybe you can create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or so that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Well I was doing so when I realized that in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63dbgcfe/) it works right. I was testing it in an ios ionic app (angular) in the safari debugger I have always seen window.myFunc1 is undefined...

Comment: Maybe you had a typo in one of the three places where the identifier `myFunc1` was used?

Comment: No I'm sure... I've been testing the four scenarios without typo (I made copy paste to `anotherFunc` and it worked)

Comment: Well, in that case it is also possible that `window.myFunc1` is a non-writable property or so, in contrast to the other three property names. Try to directly log/alert/watch the `this.myFunc1` property, don't assign it to a global.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63524/discussion-between-miquel-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1):

It may happen if you create your object in an unusual way, and `this` is bound to something different from what you expect. In my case I was exporting a constructor from the `node` module, and creating an object with `new require('module')();`, which had the same effect of prototype functions being `undefined`.